# php login button that redirects

Tags: php, html

I am a real beginner and I made a simple `login.php` but I want to know how to make the login button redirect to another page. The script I have is:

```html
<php
//Start the Session
session_start();
   
require('connect.php');

//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
    //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
    if ($count == 1) {
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    } else {
        //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}

//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hello " . $username . "
    ";
    echo "This is the Members Area
    ";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<title>Test Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Form for logging in the users -->

<div class="register-form">
<php
 if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
  echo $msg;
 }
 ?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
 <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>
 
     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>
 
    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
<php } ?>
```

and the page I want it to redirect to is in a called site/form.html located in the parent directory.
Thanks for any and all input!

Comment: tell me, is this a typo `<php` or is that part of your actual code?

Comment: `if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){` that won't run, syntax error.

Comment: am I supposed to use <?php> in dreamweaver it doesn't register unless I remove the ? it just appears as text with the question mark.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your old code has quite a few errors. This one fixes most of them, and redirects to form.html.

BTW, the line you want is `<form action="form.html" method="POST">`
Ok full code:

```
<?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
require('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }

    else{
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hello " . $username;
    echo "This is the Members Area";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<title>Test Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Form for logging in the users -->

<div class="register-form">
<?php
    if(isset($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
 ?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="form.html" method="POST">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>

     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `action="form.html"` you sure about that? Unless OP knows how to instruct Apache.

Comment: thanks! the redirect works, but since the form.html is in another folder in the parent directory would I put <form action="/site/form.html" method="POST">?

Comment: Erm, just it with `site/form.html` and `/site/form.html` not sure which one :D

Comment: works perfect! thanks, now just to make it actually save the login data haha

Comment: lol, remember to ask me if you need more help! :)

Comment: You're completely bypassing the authentication by posting the form directly to `form.html` - you need to post the data back to `login.php` and redirect with `header('Location: site/form.html');`

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
    header('Location: http://  URL to the Page You Want  /');
```

In where your successful login code is.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  If the user doesn't have an account, you would like the button to direct them to a signup page.  Right?  You could use a javascript onclick event like so.

```
 <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href='register.php' target='_parent'>Sign Up!</button>
```